# How to Change String Object to Label control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have  a string object that it queries from database. what I want is how to convert the string object to Label control. I try as shown below, but its not working properly.

```
String QueryMenu =" Select MenuLocation from tblMenu where MenuId='" + PermissionArray[i] + "'";
SqlCommand MenuExe = new SqlCommand(QueryMenu, con);
MenuExe.ExecuteScalar();
Label myLabel = this.FindControl("MenuExe") as Label;........1


myLabel.Visible = true;
```

Comment: This is asp.net, not classic asp

Comment: What do you mean `convert to Label control`? Either you are asking how to set the text of a label control, or you are asking how to find a control by name. Which is it?

Comment: BTW **don't** use string concatenation to create sql statements, it's VERY BAD practice that's both slow and exposes you to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries

Comment: What is your exact problem? What's wrong with the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Use the label's Text property to set it:

```
String QueryMenu =" Select MenuLocation from tblMenu where MenuId='" + PermissionArray[i] + "'";
SqlCommand MenuExe = new SqlCommand(QueryMenu, con);
Label myLabel = this.FindControl("MenuExe") as Label;       
myLabel.Text = (string)MenuExe.ExecuteScalar();
myLabel.Visible = true;
```

This assuming that the query returns a string

Comment: You right, the query returns string. but i need to change this string value to lable control. how to do that is the main point.

Comment: @Sapna did you read Mark's answer? It does show how to set a label's text. If you want something else you need to be specific. The phrase `How to change this string value to label control` doesn't make sense